# Conditional formating based on calculated cells

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet a sheet which records/calculates achieved Foreign Exchange rates.

There are 3 columns - € Rate; £ Used and € Got. The second two columns are given values according to the activity and the rate is a calculated cell by diving the £ Used by the € Got in each case.

The issue is that I am looking to calculate the highest (best) rate obtained and then attempting to highlight the (any) cells which meet that value.

In the Conditional Format, I am using the cell range and selecting `Is equal to` and the cell which contains the highest rate, but this instruction appears to be ignored, and nothing is highlighted.

Is this because values in calculated cells are ignored for Conditional formatting rules purposes, and if so, what workaround or different mechanism is available to achieve highlighting the highest rate?

EDIT:

So `=B4=$E$2` works (where E2 contains the best rate and B4 is the first cell across the selected range) and if set as a custom formula, the correct action takes place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following further research I have discovered the solution to this problem.

`=B4=$E$2` in a custom formula. This works across the selected range B4:J27

[image]

The result is thus:-

[image]

I used [this reference](https://www.automateexcel.com/conditional-formatting/based-on-another-cell/) to help solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

#### Conditional Foprmatting is Working

Your conditional formatting argument is working as intended, but no cells match the condition.

#### Simple Test

Place the following formula in an unrelated cell:

```
=IF(B2=F8,"Match","Don't Match")
="Don't Match"
```

#### Reason they don't match

`DIVIDE(690.08,600)=1.1501333...`

`DIVIDE(690.08,600)<>1.1501`